# How to manage jobs in google big query with python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am new to BQ and i have simple question.
There is a python script that execute every day a load table to pandas.
After the analysis the data loads to BQ and then runs another sql query for append the data to existing table.
My question is
How do i manage the jobs and check if all the data downloaded/uploaded successfully and if the last query runs without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for handling errors

```
client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig()
query_job = bigquery.job.QueryJob(str(uuid.uuid4()),
        query, client=client, job_config=job_config)
query_job._begin()
while not query_job.done():
    time.sleep(5)
if not query_job.errors:
   #TODO
```